# postgreSQL's prisma deploy command

Tags: node.js, postgresql, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I am using Nodejs, graphQl, Prisma, docker and PostgreSQL,
whenever I change Schema the I have to deploy it, but it gives error as follow

ERROR: You can not deploy to a service stage while there is a deployment in progress or a pending deployment scheduled already. Please try again after the deployment finished

"code": 4008,

"status": 200

then I wait for a few minutes and try again the result is  same, I tried a lot but the result is same

Answer (score 3):

This happens when there is an unapplied migration in the management schema.

To resolve this follow the following steps:

1. Connect to your database using a GUI(like tableplus.io))
2. Change your database schema to management schema

   [image: image|268x71]
3. Goto the migration table

   [image: image|189x59]
4. Delete the last row

[image: image|690x53]

Then try to redeploy your service.